# How to show lookup window on button click in sub grid form of CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I need your help. I want to know how to show a lookup window when user click on button which is exists in sub grid form of an entity. 
I have created a button called "Add existing Inquiries" on Inquiries entity using ribbon workbench, but don't know how to create command for the default CRM lookup window. When user click the button, lookup should open which will ask user to select record form existing entity.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `lookupObjects` method. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-utility/lookupobjects?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422)

> Opens a lookup control to select one or more items.

```
Xrm.Utility.lookupObjects(lookupOptions).then(successCallback, errorCallback)
```

Use a custom JS function command in Ribbon button, then utilize the above method in that JS webresource function.